# Onclick event issue after using the outerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, outerhtml

this is the code :

```js
$(".adauga_incasare").click(function(){
       var html = $(".incasari")[0].outerHTML;
       $(html).insertAfter($(".incasari").last());
    });

    $(".del_incasare").click(function(){
         alert("dsdasdasd");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
       <div class="incasari">
        <div class="data_incasare_container">
         <label><b>Data</b></label>
         <input class ="data_incasare" type="text" id="datepicker">
         <label class ="data_incasare_hidden">12-06-2014</label>
        </div>
        <div class="suma_incasare_container" style="">
         <label><b>Suma</b></label>
         <input class="suma_incasare" type="text" maxlength="8" name="pret_unitar[]" alt=""> 
         <label class ="suma_incasare_hidden">100</label>
        </div>
           <div class="coscos" style="">
                <a class="stergereIncasare" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
                <div class ="incasare_action">
                 <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" style="margin-left:50px;width:80px;height:30px;float:left;" value="Salveaza"></input>
                 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del_incasare delrow"></a>
              </div>
              <div style="clear:both;"></div>
           </div>
           <div style="clear:both;"></div>
          </div>
    
          <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
       <a href="#" class="adauga_incasare">+ Adauga incasare noua</a>
       <div class="toram">
         <label style = 'cursor:default;'>Total incasat: <b>100 &euro;</b></label>
         <label style = 'cursor:default;'>Total ramas: <b>1012 &euro;</b></label>
       </div>  
      </div>
```

the outerHTML works fine, but when i "clone" the class **incasari** after that , when the onclick event doesnt work on the clone part. I have a delete button. In the first class "incasari" in works , but in the clone class it does not . Why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) because your element is dynamically created after the click event was assigned. For example, to delegate to the document:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NN9wX/)**

```
$(document).on("click", ".del_incasare", function(){
    alert("dsdasdasd");
});
```

This means all clicks will be checked by the `.del_incasare` selector, and if it matches then the function will run, regardless of when the element was created.

Comment: still not works. I tried this version : $('.incasari:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.incasari:last');   and it works, but i dont undestand why

Comment: @Chester You should try to replicate in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar, because this is the correct answer.

Comment: .clone(true) will clone html element along with its attached event handlers, so it is working fine here.

Answer (score 0):

The method you used to fire click event only works with the DOM elements that has been created during page load, DOM elements created dynamically would not be handled by this method.
For the elements created after page load or dynamically you have to use Event Delegation. For this use [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$(document).on("click", ".del_incasare", function(){
    // do some cool stuff here.
});
```

You can use any parent element instead of document here, that was already in DOM during page load.